# Swift_TransportException email does not work laravel

Tags: laravel

When I run this

```
<?php 
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $from = "xyssoftware@gmail.com";
    $to = $from;
    $subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
    $message = "This is a test to check the PHP Mail functionality";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
    echo "Test email sent";
?>
```

page email works.

But when I hit my `mail::send` method it runs to this error:

> Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 268: Connection
>   could not be established with host mailtrap.io [Connection refused
>   #111]

Answer (score 0):

IF you are sending an email from your webserver and have `sendmail` and `postfix` installed.

Then you have to change your email driver from your `.env` to `MAIL_DRIVER=mail`

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

if u are in development then you can simply change the driver to log.

```
 MAIL_DRIVER=log
```

Hope this helps